# Specify returned fields in Node.js / Waterline?

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, waterline

I want to make a request like:

```
User.find().exec(function(){});
```

I know I can use `toJSON` in the model however I don't like this approach since sometimes I need different parameters. For instance if it's the logged in user I will return their email and other parameters. However if it the request fort he same data is made by a different user it would not include the email and a smaller subset of parameters.

I've also tried using:

```
User.find({}, {username:1}) ...
User.find({}, {fields: {username:1}});
```

But not having any luck. How can I specify the fields I need returned?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

So actually found a weird workaround for this. the `fields` param WILL work as long as you pass other params with it such as `limit` or `order`:

```
User.find({}, {fields: {username:1}}).limit(1);
```

Note that this will NOT work with findOne or any of the singular returning types. This means in your result callback you will need to do user[1].

Of course the other option is to just scrub your data on the way out, which is a pain if you are using a large list of items. So if anything this works for large lists where you might actually set `limit(20)` and for single items you can just explicitly return paras until `select()` is available.

Comment: This may accidentally work with the Mongo adapter, but it's definitely not a reliable solution, and the code you posted doesn't show how to actually retrieve the results (e.g. by assigning that code to a variable and calling `exec` on it).

Answer (score 11):

This is an update to the question, fields is no longer used in sails 11, please use select instead of fields.

```
Model.find({field: 'value'}, {select: ['id', 'name']})
  .paginate({page: 1}, {limit: 10})
  .exec(function(err, results) {
    if(err) {
      res.badRequest('reason');
    }
    res.json(results);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Waterline does not currently support any "select" syntax; it always returns all fields for a model.  It's currently [in development](https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline-criteria/blob/master/lib/projections/select.js) and may make it into the next release, but for now the best way to do what you want would be to use model class methods to make custom finders.  For example, `User.findUser(criteria, cb)` could find a user give `criteria`, and then check whether it was the logged-in user before deciding which data to return in the callback.