# Select specific fields from database

Tags: waterline, sails-orientdb

I just want to know that is it possible to select specific fields using waterline, orientdb query is given below.

```
e.g. 
select phone from user
```

I want to select phone from user vertices by using this query

```
userModel.find(phone)
.then(function(phonelist){ 
  if(!phonelist) 
     console.log('msg: RECORD_NOT_FOUND'); 
  else 
     console.log(phonelist);
.catch(function(err){ console.log('err: 'err'); });
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, you just need to add `select` to your search criteria, for example (assuming you are searching for a records with id 1):

```
userModel.find({ select: ['phone'], id: 1 })
```

or alternatively:

```
userModel.find({ select: ['phone'], where: { id: 1 } })
```

or if you want all records, you don't need to supply criteria:

```
userModel.find({ select: ['phone'] })
```

This doesn't seem to be documented anywhere but it should. In version 0.11 it will also possible to define select by doing `model.pick('name', 'age')`: https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/pull/952

Comment: That does not work for me in Waterline 0.10.21, I get all the fields without any selection :( - I hope 0.11 is released soon!

Comment: @FranDios, are you using sails-mongo? If so there was a bug in it that was only fixed and released 8 days ago (v0.11.3).

Comment: Yes, I do use sails-mongo. Thanks for the info, will check it :)

Comment: I've the same issue, updated sails-mongo to 0.11.3 but unfortunately the url: http://localhost:1337/modelName?select=['date'] still returns all the fields.

Comment: select works for me on sails v 0.12.13, however, how can i prevent id from tagging along with the response?

Answer (score 4):

*Source and more detail* -https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170388/1392194

Yes, it's possible but not with `select` as it's still in development. But there is a way to achieve it using `fields`.

```
Model.find({ id: id }, {
  fields: {
    name: 1,
    phoneNumber: 1
  }
}).limit(1).exec(function(...) {};
```

**This won't work with `findOne`.**

Answer (score 4):

In Sails version 1 they have added provision for sending query as well as projection to the find()/findOne() methods. You can simply do:
Model.find({where: {id: id}, select: ['name', 'phoneNumber']})

Find reference here:
https://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find#?using-projection

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **.select()** method

```
let phones = await userModel.find().select(['phone']);
```

The opposite of **.select()** is **.omit()**

Comment: This is just for sails 1.0, right?

Comment: @Xfox yes, that's right.