# WaterlineJs find() with no criteria and fields/select provided does not work

Tags: sails.js, waterline

I am trying to fetch all the records but with selected fields, I have tried the following ways but none works:

`Post.find(
    {
       where: {},
       select: ['title']
    }
);`

`Post.find(
    {},
    {
      fields: {
          title: 1
       }
    }
);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24170388/1100528) answer points out, the fields param "WILL work as long as you pass other params with it such as `limit` or `order`."

Alternatively, if you want this throughout your application, you could define a custom `toJSON` function for your model, under `attributes`. If not, you could still define it under some other (e.g. `filter`) and use `map` to return the custom objects instead of the default model. Remember to take care of the control flow while using `map` though. Use async/promises/raw logic to avoid returning before all objects are processed.

Answer (score 1):

The issue has been resolved in sails-mongo latest version:

https://github.com/balderdashy/waterline/issues/1098

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've played with trying to get above answer to use limit or order to kick in the projection to no avail.

I did see this in the docs located here:
http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/native

With an out of the box solution for exactly what you're doing (pasted here for ease of use).

```
Pet.native(function(err, collection) {
    if (err) return res.serverError(err);

    collection.find({}, {
        name: true
    }).toArray(function (err, results) {
        if (err) return res.serverError(err);
        return res.ok(results);
   });
});
```

Swap out the response base things and change Pet to Post and, this ought to work in the sails console:

```
Post.native(function(err, collection) {
  if (err) throw new Error(err);

  collection.find({}, {
     title: true
  }).toArray(function (err, results) {
    if (err) throw new Error(err);
    console.log(results);
  });
});
```

You'll still get the _id field, and if you don't want that then hit the Mongo docs on not getting those *hint*(title: true, _id: false)*hint*

Hope this helps!